# How to interact with the language settings in Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, settings

I need to make a program that will change the language on windows, But I have no idea how to do it. How can I do this? Which interface i need? Where get the documentation?

Comment: UI language? Keyboard language? Current user? New users? Logon screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10, you can **TRY** this (without *needing* a program):

1. Open up your Windows's `Settings`
2. Go to `Time & Language`

In there, you can adjust your preferred languages for your Windows (apps, websites, regional format, keyboard,...)

You can install other language packs if you need to.